# My ActionCable doesn't stream data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stream, actioncable

I have a problem with actioncable.
I have two channels ( Notification and Post) but only Notification stream data to received method and not Post .

**PostChannel** look like this => 
`class PostChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
     stream_from "post_channel__user_#{current_user.id}"
  end
def unsubscribed
    # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
  end
end`
**PostBroadcastJob** looks like this => 
`class PostBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default
def perform(match)
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "post_channel_user_#{match.user_id}",  match: render_matching(match)
  end
 private
 def render_matching(match)
    ApplicationController.renderer.render(partial: 'match/match', locals: { match: match })
  end 
end`

**Where I call the job** looks like this =>`def create
     if params[:remotipart_submitted]
       respond_to do |f|
         @post = current_user.posts.create(post_params)
         @ma = Post.matching(@post.Heure,@post.Date,@post.type_activite_id).second
         if @ma.nil?
           puts " Aucun match"
         else
           match=@ma
           PostBroadcastJob.perform_later(match)
         end
         f.html { redirect_to user_url(current_user)}
         f.js
    end
     else
       flash[:danger]= "nooooooo"
     end
end`

And **my coffe file** looks like this => `App.post = App.cable.subscriptions.create "PostChannel",
  connected: ->

## Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server

disconnected: ->

## Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server

received: (match) ->

## Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel

```
$('#notificationList').prepend "okok #{match}"`
```

**Results** => `[ActiveJob] Enqueued NotificationBroadcastJob (Job ID: 59cf14ec-4f76-4b7d-af80-b0bcf6c65986) to Async(default) with arguments: 9, #<GlobalID:0xe483670 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://see-u/Notification/89>>
  Notification Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "notifications".* FROM "notifications" WHERE "notifications"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 89], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Post Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE (Heure BETWEEN '2000-01-01 10:54:00 UTC' AND '2000-01-01 12:54:00 UTC' AND Date = '2017-06-27' AND type_activite_id = '9') ORDER BY "posts"."created_at" DESC LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 1], ["OFFSET", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [59cf14ec-4f76-4b7d-af80-b0bcf6c65986] Performing NotificationBroadcastJob from Async(default) with arguments: 9, #<GlobalID:0xe461668 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://see-u/Notification/89>>
[ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [59cf14ec-4f76-4b7d-af80-b0bcf6c65986]   Relationship Load (0.0ms)  Select followed_id from relationships where follower_id =10
  Rendered match/_match.html.erb (0.0ms)
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to post_channel_user_8: {:match=>"kklklkklkllklklklk"}
[ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [59cf14ec-4f76-4b7d-af80-b0bcf6c65986]   Rendered notifications/_counter.erb (4.0ms)
[ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [59cf14ec-4f76-4b7d-af80-b0bcf6c65986]   User Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 10], ["LIMIT", 1]]
[ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [59cf14ec-4f76-4b7d-af80-b0bcf6c65986]   Rendered notifications/_notification.html.erb (3.0ms)
[ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [59cf14ec-4f76-4b7d-af80-b0bcf6c65986] [ActionCable] Broadcasting to notification_channel_user_7: {:counter=>"<li class=\"zoome\">\n  <img src=\"/assets/alarm-3bb640e80c366ebf278c6ed6d5cc214cefed0b62e6af95d3436dc438b5e6a250.png\" alt=\"Alarm\" />\n  <span  id=\"notification-counter\">9</span>\n</li>", :notification=>"<li style=\"text-decoration: none;border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;\">\n\n<div class=\"row\" style=\"margin-bottom: 0px\">\n  <span class=\"col s2\" style=\"margin-top: 23px\">\n\n\n          <img height=\"55\" width=\"55\" src=\"/system/users/avatars/000/000/010/thumb/boir2.jpg?1491145350\" alt=\"Boir2\" />\n\n\n  </span>\n\n  <span class=\"col s10\" style=\"margin-top: 15px\"> <a style=\"color: crimson;font-size: 13px\" href=\"/users/10\">Nouvelle activitÃ© proposÃ©e par Ng</a></span>\n\n\n\n</div>\n\n</li>"}
[ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [59cf14ec-4f76-4b7d-af80-b0bcf6c65986]   Rendered notifications/_counter.erb (85.0ms)
  Rendering posts/create.js.erb
[ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [59cf14ec-4f76-4b7d-af80-b0bcf6c65986]   Rendered notifications/_notification.html.erb (0.0ms)
[ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [59cf14ec-4f76-4b7d-af80-b0bcf6c65986] [ActionCable] Broadcasting to notification_channel_user_8: {:counter=>"<li class=\"zoome\">\n  <img src=\"/assets/alarm-3bb640e80c366ebf278c6ed6d5cc214cefed0b62e6af95d3436dc438b5e6a250.png\" alt=\"Alarm\" />\n  <span  id=\"notification-counter\">9</span>\n</li>", :notification=>"<li style=\"text-decoration: none;border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;\">\n\n<div class=\"row\" style=\"margin-bottom: 0px\">\n  <span class=\"col s2\" style=\"margin-top: 23px\">\n\n\n          <img height=\"55\" width=\"55\" src=\"/system/users/avatars/000/000/010/thumb/boir2.jpg?1491145350\" alt=\"Boir2\" />\n\n\n  </span>\n\n  <span class=\"col s10\" style=\"margin-top: 15px\"> <a style=\"color: crimson;font-size: 13px\" href=\"/users/10\">Nouvelle activitÃ© proposÃ©e par Ng</a></span>\n\n\n\n</div>\n\n</li>"}
[ActiveJob] [NotificationBroadcastJob] [59cf14ec-4f76-4b7d-af80-b0bcf6c65986] Performed NotificationBroadcastJob from Async(default) in 1075.4ms
NotificationsChannel transmitting {"counter"=>"<li class=\"zoome\">\n  <img src=\"/assets/alarm-3bb640e80c366ebf278c6ed6d5cc214cefed0b62e6af95d3436dc438b5e6a250.png\" alt=\"Alarm\" />\n  <span  id=\"notification-counter\">9</span>\n</li>", "notification"=>"<li style=\"text-decoration: none;border-bottom: 1px dotted gray;\">\n\n<d... (via streamed from notification_channel_user_8)
  Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (19.5ms)
  Rendered posts/create.js.erb (40.4ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3594ms (Views: 722.0ms | ActiveRecord: 205.7ms)`

**Thanks you to all for your help**

Answer (score 1):

stream_from "post_channel__user_#{current_user.id}"
&
ActionCable.server.broadcast "post_channel_user_#{match.user_id}"

"post_channel__user_" != "post_channel_user_"

Comment: Thank you ahaha sometimes when you are focus , i forget some little things :D